# Regex in Yahoo Pipes: Add content only if 1) string A exists and 2) string B doesn't exist

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I wanted to add a hashtag based on two patters, how would I combine them? Example: I want to add "#Oil" only if a) the existing content contains "crude" AND b) does not contain "oil".

My existing pipe is [here](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=c85a7960bd7178f5eae396f5df070b2c) - top left Regex module, bottom two rules show the existing criteria: replace `.*Hydraulic Fracturing.*` with `$0 #Fracking`.

Comment: This is much too vague a description. Include at a link to your pipe and (for reference) a screenshot of your current setup, plus an explanation what data is fed to what input.

Comment: Tomalak, I edited my question and added the info you asked, I hope.

Comment: The point with the "existing pipe" is that it's a moving target. Make a change and your question can no longer be understood. That's why I said "screenshot". :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add "#Oil" only if a) the existing content contains "crude" AND b) does not contain "oil".

I see what you mean.

You are looking for look-ahead assertions.

That's: `^(?=.*?\bcrude\b)(?!.*\boil\b).*`. Note that `\b` denotes a word boundary.

The expression goes like this

```
^                  # start-of-string
(?=                # positive look-ahead
  .*?              #   any number of characters, lazily
  \bcrude\b        #   the word "crude"
)                  # end look-ahead
(?!                # negative look-ahead
  .*?              #   any number of characters, lazily
  \boil\b          #   the word "oil"
)                  # end look-ahead
.*                 # match any characters (i.e. the entire string)
```

Replace with `$0 #Oil` and you're done.

The assertions make sure that a) "crude" exists somewhere in the string and b) "oil" does not. After that the entire string is considered a hit and "#Oil" gets appended.

Further reading:

- [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) vs. [lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) matching